# How to use type information from pattern matching?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, type-inference

I have the following setup:

```
trait TypeA { override def toString() = "A" }
trait TypeB { override def toString() = "B" }
trait TypeC { override def toString() = "C" }

def foo[T](t: T) = println(t)
```

Now I can do something like this:

```
val valueB: Any = new TypeB {}

val typedValue = valueB match {
  case t: TypeA => foo(t)
  case t: TypeB => foo(t)
  case t: TypeC => foo(t)
}
// prints "B"
```

If I want to generalize this pattern matching block, I can simply do:

```
val typedValue = valueB match {
  case t => foo(t)
}
```

and it will work. However, in my real use case I need to explicitly state the type information when invoking the method because there is no function argument to infer it from. So **if `foo()` was a generic method parameterized with type parameter `T`, but without actual parameters of that type to infer from, can I generalize this into a pattern matching with just one case statement** (probably using the Reflection API)?

So, how to generalize this?

```
val typedValue = valueB match {
  case t: TypeA => foo[TypeA]()
  case t: TypeB => foo[TypeB]()
  case t: TypeC => foo[TypeC]()
  ...
}
```

Comment: This appears to compile: `case t => foo[t.type]()` Give it a try.

Comment: The tough part is, how to make the pattern matching really extract the actual type? I would like to be able to say `val t: Any = ...` and in the pattern matching part I would match on the actual type. See the edited question (val valueB is now of type `Any`). If `valueB` is declared to be of type `Any`, your suggestion unfortunately doesn't work, and with a weird message too (unspecified value parameters: t.type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to generalize this pattern matching block, I can simply do:
>
> ```
> val typedValue = valueB match {
>   case t => foo(t)
> }
> ```

In general you can't. E.g. if `foo(x: TypeA)`, `foo(x: TypeB)` and `foo(x: TypeC)` are separate overloads. And that's the situation for your real code: you'd have to write separate methods for `JsObject`, etc. because those `value` calls just happen to have the same name; you can't write `foo(x: JsValue)` or `foo[T <: JsValue](x: T)` which would do what you want (without the same match which you want to avoid).

In the case where you do have a single polymorphic method: because generic arguments get erased, if you have `def foo[T]() = ...`, `foo[TypeA]()`, `foo[TypeB]()` and `foo[TypeC]()` will execute the same actual code (this doesn't apply to `classOf`, `isInstanceOf` or `asInstanceOf`, but those are the only exceptions and it's because they aren't really generic methods). So you can just call `foo[<type-of-valueB>]`. For them to be different, `foo` has to have an implicit argument which depends on `T`, e.g.

```
trait Baz[A] { ... }
object Baz {
  implicit val bazTypeA: Baz[TypeA] = ...
  ...
}

def foo[A]()(implicit baz: Baz[A]) = ...
```

In this case the way to avoid branching is for the method calling `foo` to accept the same implicit:

```
def bar[A](value: A)(implicit baz: Baz[A]) = foo[A]()

bar(new TypeA) // uses bazTypeA
```

Comment: Can you explain how does this work? It's a snippet using Play JSON; if you're not familiar with it, you'll get the point anyway.. Isn't JsNumber and JsString resolved at runtime and thus should be erased?  
    
`val result = json match { case jsString: JsString => json.as[JsNumber].value }  // doesn't work`
  
and  
  
`val result = json match { case jsString: JsString => json.as[JsString].value } // works`

One would expect that two calls, `as[JsString]` and `as[JsNumber]`, trigger the same code like you said. But the type parameter makes a big difference.

Comment: `as` uses an implicit argument, which is covered at the end of my answer.